# post method is empty in yii1 restful api

Tags: php, api, rest, yii, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to get POST method working in yii 1 rest full api, but no success,

```
namespace frontend\controllers;
use yii;
use yii\rest\Controller;
use common\models\RegistrationForm;
use dektrium\user\models\ResendForm;
use common\models\User;
use common\models\Profile;
use dektrium\user\traits\AjaxValidationTrait;
use dektrium\user\traits\EventTrait;
use yii\db\Expression;
use common\models\Messages;
use common\models\MessagesSearch;
use common\models\MessagesRecipients;
use yii\db\Query;
use yii\db\Command;
use yii\web\Response;
use frontend\controllers\ApiResponderBase;
use dektrium\user\models\Token;
use dektrium\user\models\RecoveryForm;

class ApkController extends Controller
{
  public function actionResetpassword()
  {
    $request = \Yii::$app->request->post(); $post =  (file_get_contents("php://input")); 
   print_r($request);
  }
}
```

I have tried everything I can do, looking forward 
Postman Screenshot
[image: Postman view]

Comment: Why are you sending this as `form-data`, and not `x-www-form-urlencoded`? Unless you are doing a file upload, there is no reason to use the former.

Comment: @CBroe I did with  x-www-form-urlencoded as well, but the output is same https://prnt.sc/sh6puu

Comment: And what do you get for `$post`?

Comment: @CBroe nothing , https://prnt.sc/sh8g2l

Comment: Then check what the actual request method is, `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);` If that is _not_ POST - then you probably got a redirect or something like that going on there.

Comment: @CBroe it is showing GET but I am sensing POST , https://prnt.sc/sh8n72

Comment: Well then either you are sending the request to the wrong endpoint to begin with (maybe it needs a trailing slash?) - or something is messed up with your routing setup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213916/discussion-between-24-coded-and-cbroe).